# How to ignore vendor folder in the project root

Tags: vim, ctrlp

I'm using vim+ctrlp and I have a project who has multiple vendor folders, one in the root directory (for vendor packages), and another inside resources/views/vendor.

I have the following in my ctrlp ignore configuration

```
let g:ctrlp_custom_ignore = {
    \ 'dir':  '\.git$\|\.hg$\|\.svn$\|node_modules$\|vendor$\|smarty$\|static$\|node_modules',
    \ 'file': '\.exe$\|\.so$\|\.dll$\|\.pyc$\|\.png$'
}
```

Of course, this ignore both vendor directories. From the doc's of ctrlp

> Note: to ignore a root directory "build", and not *any* directory with
>         "build" in it, you can root the regex: ^build$

So I tried to add `^vendor$`:

```
let g:ctrlp_custom_ignore = {
    \ 'dir':  '\.git$\|\.hg$\|\.svn$\|node_modules$\|smarty$\|static$\|node_modules\|^vendor$',
    \ 'file': '\.exe$\|\.so$\|\.dll$\|\.pyc$\|\.png$'
}
```

This doesn't work and now I see the root vendor folder. The root of ctrlp is correctly setted to the project root (where the vendor I wanna ignore is).

Comment: This would appear to either a bug in the implementation or in the documentation. (I've just verified that the suggested solution doesn't work for me either.) I'd suggest opening an issue on the ctrlp repo.

Comment: Thanks @pdoherty926, I'm gonna follow that suggestion